# react native expo app shows blank screen in production only

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I've a react native app built with expo that is showing a blank white screen in production after I released it to Play Store Closed Testing.

Previous app versions have worked before, but this is my first time using Internal Testing. Also, it seems to work on some devices, but shows the blank screen on others.

I've tried using `expo start --no-dev --minify` and also `expo run:android --variant release` but was still unable to reproduce the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does .apk build work on the device?
please provide more information.

Comment: @HamidAsiabari i don't have a device to test the apk directly, i'll have to try that another time

Comment: More information about packages and configs would be helpful for recognizing the cause and if you want I can test it for you.

Comment: @NathanTew did you try to install the apk at your emulator via drag & drop?

Comment: @MichaelBahl yes I did. I think it’s an issue with expo’s useFonts hook randomly failing: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/21885

Comment: I am having the same issue on ios both simulator and real device using dev build